# A simple script/plugin to display specific page upon hierarchy of selections

Tags: plugins, hierarchical

I am building up a shop in wordpress using mayashop theme. What i need is a page where i can display two categories - Men and Women. Upon selecting one, it should open up a list of sub categories. There is one more level deep sub categories and on final selection it should redirect to a page based on the 3 selection. I got several different pages so its not like i need to send parameters or something. 
The basic solution would be to create a hell lot of pages, which i don't want to do. So is there any plugin or some script which i can put on a page that can display the hierarchy in a decent manner??

I tried making something like [this](http://fitreaks.y4y.in/?page_id=188) but it couldn't go beyond 2 levels and it doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already have the two particular category IDs, so list the sub-categories. Like so:

```
$cat_list_1 = wp_list_categories(array(
    'echo' => 1,
    'child_of' => FIRST_CAT_ID_HERE,
    'title_li' => 'A Name for This',
    'depth' => 2, // or whatever you like
));

$cat_list_2 = wp_list_categories(array(
    'echo' => 1,
    'child_of' => SECOND_CAT_ID_HERE,
    'title_li' => 'Another Name for This',
    'depth' => 2, // or whatever you like
));
```

This generates two lists containing links to the categories (which you first have to define in your WP admin, of course).
Then it's just a matter of CSS/jQuery to style and tweak the lists as you see fit.

If you want/have to *work* with the HTML of the lists before printing it, use `'echo' => 0`. Then you're able to do `preg_replace` or whatever, and finally `echo` the variables.

See [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for full listing of the parameters.

Comment: I need to display some specific pages for which i do not want to create a category. With your solution, i cannot include my own URL's. And actually it mainly about the design. I am sure there must be some script which can display fancy collapsing boxes to provide choices.

Comment: Well, first, your question says "display two categories" and "list of sub categories" so I just provided what you've asked for. If you meant something else, I'd say you should edit your question. And second, the _fancy collapsing boxes_ part is CSS (and maybe a bit of jQuery), which is not WP-sepcific. Maybe try over at StackOverflow?

Comment: By category i meant general categories. Like in my case its men and women. Sorry about the confusion. You can visit the link to see what i am trying to create. Any WP plugins for that ??